# What algorithm does .NET use to generate primes for RSA and how can I verify it?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

There is an implementation of RSA in C# .net, but how can people know that this implementation is considering all the secury stuff conserning to RSA?

For example I want to know what is the algorithm that they use to generate prime $p$ and $q$, and how the verify that that primes are good primes and they don't need to look for another pair. 
Also, what value of $e$ they are choosen?

Is there some documentation with this kind of information aviable online?

Best regards,

Comment: Probably people just trust in Microsoft knowing what they are doing most of the time...

Answer (score 6):

> There is an implementation of RSA in C# .net,

That depends on what you mean by "implementation".

In .NET Framework there are two built-in classes which provide RSA functionality:

- `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider` (mscorlib.dll)
- `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng` (System.Core.dll)

In .NET Core there are 3.5 classes:

- `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider` (System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll, some functionality Windows-only)
- `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng` (System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll, Windows-only)
- `System.Security.Cryptography.RSAOpenSsl` (System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll, non-Windows-only, requires OpenSsl 1.0.x on the system)
- The opaque type returned by `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create()` (System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll)

None of those actually "implement" RSA, in that none of them really understand modulus, exponent, or CRT.

> What value of $e$ they are choosen?

All of the inbox providers use F4 / 65537 / 0x010001 as the value for the public exponent with their default options.

> I want to know what is the algorithm that they use to generate prime $p$ and $q$

That's up to the underlying library.  In some cases, that's up to an underlying library for the underlying library.

#### RSACryptoServiceProvider (.NET Framework, .NET Core on Windows)

The key is created with [`CryptGenKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379941(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unless configured differently with a `CspParameters` value in the constructor(s) which accept(s) one the type uses `PROV_RSA_AES` with the default provider for that ProvType (`MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV` / "Microsoft AES Cryptographic Provider") and a key in the AT_EXCHANGE slot.

#### RSACryptoServiceProvider (.NET Core on non-Windows)

Skip ahead to RSA.Create(), this is just a compatibility type on non-Windows systems.

#### RSACng (.NET Framework, .NET Core on Windows)

The key is created with [`NCryptCreatePersistedKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376247(v=vs.85).aspx) using a `null` name (making it an ephemeral key) and the `Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider` provider.

To create keys using other providers someone can call a [`CngKey.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.create(v=vs.110).aspx) overload and pass the pre-created key to `new RSACng(CngKey)`.

#### RSAOpenSsl (.NET Core, non-Windows)

Keys are created using [`RSA_generate_key_ex`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RSA_generate_key_ex.html) with a fixed $e$ = $65537$, and an `RSA*` created with [`RSA_new`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RSA_new.html) (the default engine).

#### RSA.Create() (.NET Core)

On .NET Core an opaque type is used for platform-independent RSA functionality.  On Windows it's functionally equivalent to using `RSACng`.  On Linux (and any other *NIX other than macOS (or including macOS for the 1.0 or 1.1 releases)) it's functionally equivalent to using `RSAOpenSsl`.

Starting with .NET Core 2.0 the macOS version is powered by a non-public type which creates the key using [`SecKeyGeneratePair`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395339-seckeygeneratepair?language=objc).

#### Completing the matrix

`RSAOpenSsl` doesn't exist at all on .NET Framework, and throws `PlatformNotSupportedException` on .NET Core for Windows.  `RSACng` throws `PlatformNotSupportedException` on .NET Core for systems-other-than-Windows.

On .NET Framework `RSA.Create()` emits an instance of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, unless configured differently via `CryptoConfig`.

#### Other types

RSA is an open type, so anyone is free to write an RSA provider for .NET.  This post contains all of the types that ship as part of .NET (Framework or Core) and provide RSA functionality... for any other types you'd need to track down their owners.

---

So, I know that doesn't *really* answer your question; but it does give you places you can go to further hunt things down if you want to know the answers.

The proof of these statements for .NET Core can be found at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/.  RSACng on .NET Framework at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/, and for RSACryptoServiceProvider on .NET Framework a combination of referencesource and a debugger (the actual call to CryptGenKey lives within clr.dll, which is not published on referencesource).

Oh, and Mono and Xamarin are probably doing something completely different.